# How can I get Linux to show total CPU usage?

Tags: linux, cpu, monitoring, resources

I want to show how much the CPU is used over time.

Using system monitor, I am able to show CPU usage, but only the 4 individual cores. I want to be able to show a graph of the total CPU usage.

In other words, CPU core 1+2+3+4 = total, total <- graph

Comment: This really depends on what window manager you're using, unless you're looking for a specific application.  Off-hand, I know GNOME and XFCE both include a CPU graph, so it's likely your system already has one built into the WM - see if you can add any "widgets" or taskbar entries...

Comment: I think the 'top' command shows the total usage (as opposed to pressing '1' which shows the individual cores)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conky to do this.

Conky is an application that draws an overlay on your desktop showing different system information. You can customise what is shown by creating a ".conkyrc" file in your home directory.

This is the .conkyrc file I use (It's a modified version of the one in PartedMagic):

```
# the list of variables has been removed from this file in favour
# of keeping the documentation more maintainable.
# Check http://conky.sf.net for an up-to-date-list.

# set to yes if you want Conky to be forked in the background
background yes

# X font when Xft is disabled, you can pick one with program xfontsel
#font 5x7
#font 6x10
font 7x13
#font 8x13
#font 9x15
#font *mintsmild.se*
#font -*-*-*-*-*-*-34-*-*-*-*-*-*-*

# Use Xft?
use_xft no

# Xft font when Xft is enabled
xftfont Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:size=11

# Text alpha when using Xft
xftalpha 0.8

# Print everything to stdout?
# out_to_console no

# Print everything to console?
# out_to_console no

# Update interval in seconds
update_interval 5.0

# This is the number of times Conky will update before quitting.
# Set to zero to run forever.
total_run_times 0

#own_window_title Parted Magic - conky

# Create own window instead of using desktop (required in nautilus)
own_window yes

# If own_window is yes, you may use type normal, desktop or override
own_window_type normal

# Use pseudo transparency with own_window?
own_window_transparent yes

# If own_window_transparent is set to no, you can set the background colour here
own_window_colour black

# If own_window is yes, these window manager hints may be used
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
#own_window_hints below,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

# Use double buffering (reduces flicker, may not work for everyone)
double_buffer yes

# Minimum size of text area
minimum_size 280 5

# Draw shades?
draw_shades yes

# Draw outlines?
draw_outline no

# Draw borders around text
draw_borders no

# Draw borders around graphs
draw_graph_borders yes

# Stippled borders?
stippled_borders 4

# border margins
border_margin 4

# border width
border_width 1

# Default colors and also border colors
default_color white
default_shade_color black
default_outline_color black

# Text alignment, other possible values are commented
#alignment top_left
alignment top_right
#alignment bottom_left
#alignment bottom_right
#alignment none

# Gap between borders of screen and text
# same thing as passing -x at command line
gap_x 15
gap_y 15

# Subtract file system buffers from used memory?
no_buffers yes

# set to yes if you want all text to be in uppercase
uppercase no

# number of cpu samples to average
# set to 1 to disable averaging
cpu_avg_samples 2

# number of net samples to average
# set to 1 to disable averaging
net_avg_samples 2

# Force UTF8? note that UTF8 support required XFT
override_utf8_locale no

# Add spaces to keep things from moving about?  This only affects certain objects.
use_spacer none

TEXT
${color goldenrod}Hostname: $nodename
${color goldenrod}Linux Kernel: $kernel
${color goldenrod}CPU Details:  $machine, $freq(MHz)
${color}CPU History:  ${color darkgreen}${cpugraph 30,0 0000ff 00ff00}
${color}CPU Usage:${color magenta2} $cpu% ${cpubar 11,0}

${color}RAM Usage:${color DeepSkyBlue1} $mem ($memperc%) ${membar 11,0}
${color}Available RAM:${color DeepSkyBlue1} $memmax

$color$stippled_hr
$alignc${color}Processes:$color $processes  ${color grey}Running:$color $running_processes
$alignc${color}(top 5 sorted by CPU usage)
${color goldenrod} NAME              PID    CPU%   MEM%
${color} ${top name 1} ${top pid 1} ${top cpu 1} ${top mem 1}
${color} ${top name 2} ${top pid 2} ${top cpu 2} ${top mem 2}
${color} ${top name 3} ${top pid 3} ${top cpu 3} ${top mem 3}
${color} ${top name 4} ${top pid 4} ${top cpu 4} ${top mem 4}
${color} ${top name 5} ${top pid 5} ${top cpu 5} ${top mem 5}

$alignc${color}(top 5 sorted by MEM usage)
${color goldenrod} NAME              PID    CPU%   MEM%
${color} ${top_mem name 1} ${top_mem pid 1} ${top_mem cpu 1} ${top_mem mem 1}
${color} ${top_mem name 2} ${top_mem pid 2} ${top_mem cpu 2} ${top_mem mem 2}
${color} ${top_mem name 3} ${top_mem pid 3} ${top_mem cpu 3} ${top_mem mem 3}
${color} ${top_mem name 4} ${top_mem pid 4} ${top_mem cpu 4} ${top_mem mem 4}
${color} ${top_mem name 5} ${top_mem pid 5} ${top_mem cpu 5} ${top_mem mem 5}
$color$stippled_hr
$alignc${color}System Uptime:${color DarkOrange1} $uptime
${color} Battery: $battery_short ($battery_time) ${color grey} ${battery_bar 11,0}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a way to get the overall CPU usage number which you can then graph:

```
echo print `top -n 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d$" " -f10 | tail -n +8 | head -n -1 | paste -sd+ | bc`/ `nproc` | python
```

Source: https://mohammadg.com/linux/how-to-get-overall-cpu-utilization-from-the-bash-command-line/